# Lyapunov Function for non-autonomous systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

I wanted to find somewhere (a book or a set of online notes would be ideal) that had the exact theorem about lyapunov functions and how they determine stability but in the case of non-autonomous systems

$$
\dot{x} = f(x,t)
$$

Comment: What kind of stability do you want to show using a Lyapunov function: Lyapunov, asymptotic or exponential?

Comment: So I believe there's a theorem for an autonomous ode that says

Let W be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x^* \in W$. Suppose there exists a function  $V:W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, V \in C^1(W)$, satisfying $V(x^*) = 0$ and $V(x)>0$ for all $x \in W \setminus \{x^*\}$. Then If:

i) $\dot{V}(x(t)) \leq 0$ for all $x \in W \setminus \{x^*\}$ then $x^*$ is stable 

ii) $\dot{V}(x(t)) < 0$ for all $x \in W \setminus \{x^*\}$ then $x^*$ is asymptotically stable


I want something of a similar form but also taking about a time dependent ode

Comment: I'm looking to show 
$$
f(x(t))-f(x^*) \leq \frac{\|x(0)-x^*\|^2}{t^2}
$$
for a particular ode, I've got the function but I want the theorem to show it satsifies the conditions.